I cannot REFRESH my External table at Snowflake
Im trying to refresh an external table but it is not working.
I need to REFRESH the table manually since I don't have an explicit periodicity to make it automatically. Also read the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-external-table#add-or-remove-files-manually
I made the following:

I created my external table by:

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE  DB.PUBLIC.TABLE_1( <columns goes here> ) LOCATION = @S3_stage/table_1/ FILE_FORMAT = ( FORMAT_NAME = 'parquet' );
I tested it was working and it worked. The table was created with it's information.

Then I tried to refresh the table by using:

ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE DB.PUBLIC.TABLE_1 REFRESH @S3_stage/table_1/date_year=2024/date_month=5/;
but it's not working. I've also tried to REMOVE or ADD files with:
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE DB.PUBLIC.TABLE_1 REMOVE FILES ('date_year=2024/date_month=5/');
but it isn't working either. When I get the query results it shows me an error "UNREGISTER_FAILED" with the description "File unregistration failed: No such file." BUT when I observe the "file" column at the results it shows me the right path table_1/date_year=2024/date_month=5/
Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?
